# How to load entire website (external link) with functionality on my webpage?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, elasticsearch

I want to integrate [this external example link](http://demo.elastic.co/app/kibana#/dashboard/Metricbeat-system-overview?_g=h@44136fa&_a=h@a452dc1) on my web page. I am using PHP scripting language.

I have used file_get_contents, wget and all things but its only get HTML content.

I want to load entire site on my webpage. I don't want to use Iframe and tags because of security purpose I cant share URL with Users.

So please give me advice on this.

Is this we can do like how the proxy site works? Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: This works for me: `<?php echo file_get_contents("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45229653/how-to-load-entire-website-external-link-with-functionality-on-my-webpage");?>`

Comment: but its only load html content not js and ajax calls!!

Comment: Because it will not have your session with it.

Comment: didn't  get you ! :(

Comment: So you have any suggestion or code?

Comment: If you copy the code snippet I posted above you will see this question page but you will notice that your will not be logged in although you are logged in actually. This happens because file_get_content does not retain your session.

Comment: I got you but I dont want session url at all. try this url (http://demo.elastic.co/app/kibana#/dashboard/Metricbeat-system-overview?_g=h@44136fa&_a=h@a452dc1)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149770/discussion-between-harsh-and-himanshu-upadhyay).